# C++ dynamic array ADT

Tags: arrays, c++11, dynamic

What I am trying to create is a dynamic array to keep track of the annual salary increase rate since the year of employment. I have finished everything but the dynamic array. Not sure if you guys need my header file too, but here's what I've got thus far.

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

//default constructor 
Employee::Employee():Person()
{
    years_employment = 0;
    annualSalary_increaseRate = NULL;
}

Employee::Employee(int newID, string newName, DayOfYear date, int day, int month, int year, int employ_years, double bSalary, double aSalary): Person(newID,newName,date), eday(day), emonth(month), eyear(year), years_employment(employ_years), basesalary(bSalary), annualsalary(aSalary), annualSalary_increaseRate(NULL)
{

}
//destructor
Employee::~Employee()
{   
    if (annualSalary_increaseRate !=NULL)
    {
        delete [] annualSalary_increaseRate;
        annualSalary_increaseRate = NULL;
        years_employment = 0;
    }
}
   //call the copy constructor of the base class
   Employee::Employee(const Employee & emp)
   {
       years_employment = emp.years_employment;
       if (years_employment <= 0) 
       {
          annualSalary_increaseRate = NULL;
       } 
       else 
       {
           annualSalary_increaseRate = new double[years_employment];
           // Copy data
           for (int i = 0; i < years_employment; i++) 
           {
               annualSalary_increaseRate[i] = emp.annualSalary_increaseRate[i];
           }
       } 
  }
Employee Employee::operator=(const Employee& rhs)
{
    years_employment = rhs.years_employment;
    if (years_employment <= 0) 
    {
        annualSalary_increaseRate = NULL;
    } 
    else 
    {
        annualSalary_increaseRate = new double[years_employment];
        // Copy data
        for (int i = 0; i < years_employment; i++) 
        {
            annualSalary_increaseRate[i] = rhs.annualSalary_increaseRate[i];
        }
    }   
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Employee& emp)
{
    out << "---------------------------------\n";
    out << "Employment Years: " << emp.years_employment << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < emp.years_employment; i++)
    {
        int y = i+1;
        double percent = emp.annualSalary_increaseRate[i] * 100;
        out << "Year " << y << " Annual Salary Increase: " << percent << endl;
    }
    out << endl;
    out << "---------------------------------\n";

    return out;
}

void Employee::output() const
{
   cout << "----------------------------------\n";
   cout << "Employment Years: " << years_employment << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < years_employment; i++)
    {
        int y = i+1;
        double percent = annualSalary_increaseRate[i] * 100;
        cout << "Year " << y << " Annual Salary Increase: " << percent << endl;
    }

   cout << endl;
   cout << "----------------------------------\n";
}
```

This is what i need help with:

```
void Employee::set_annualSalary_increaseRate(double rate[], int yrs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < years_employment; i++)
    {
        double dec = rate[i]/100;
        annualSalary_increaseRate[i] = dec; //convert the percentage to decimal
    }
}

string Employee::get_annualSalary_increaseRate()const 
{
    stringstream temp;
    string anSal_incrRate;
    for (int i = 0; i < years_employment; i++)
    {
        int y = i+1;
        double percent = annualSalary_increaseRate[i] * 100;  //convert back to percentage
        temp << "Year " << y << " Annual Salary Increase: %" << percent << endl;
    }
    anSal_incrRate = temp.str();

    return anSal_incrRate;
}
```

I have already tested the other functions and it all works fine, so i just typed out the parts that count and they are just the parts that involves the dynamic array.
So even though my program does compile, it crashes when I run it. Running it in debug mode, it crashes on this line:

```
annualSalary_increaseRate[i] = dec;
```

With the error: `Program received signal SIGEGV, Segmentation fault`
im not quite sure whats going on. I'm still fairly new to dynamic arrays and after googling a bunch of sites I'm just getting more confused. Is it because I need to delete[] the array? or is it something else.
Thank you all in advance

Comment: A dynamic array is also called [a vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: As for your problem, a good start may be to look at the `set_annualSalary_increaseRate`. You do know that once you have deleted memory you should not access it again?

Comment: lol forgot to take that out. but result is still the same

Comment: What do you mean by the adt in the title?

Comment: because the assignment involves polymorphism and inheritance, though i see you point as my question is more with my problem with the dynamic array than that

Answer (score 0):

For a good understanding of what goes wrong here, it is important to understand what a dynamic array is, and what a constant array is.

- A dynamic array will change it's size during it's lifetime. That is, you don't need to declare it with a specific size. It will just increase it's size during it's lifetime.
- A constant array is an array which upon creation allocates space and therefore cannot be expanded over this size. You could of course keep a separate variable indicating the number of slots you use, reducing the used length of the array. You can however never exceed it's maximum size.

You are getting a segmentation fault because you are exceeding the length of the array. If you want to avoid this it is the easiest to use a dynamic array. 
Now dynamic arrays come in a couple of different flavours:

- `std::queue` Used as a buffer where you insert elements in the front, and extract them at the back. In a lot of cases this is all you need.
- `std::deque` A double ended queue. Identical to the latter, with the diffence being that extraction and insertion can both be done at each end.
- `std::vector` What you will probably need in this particular case. Insertion can be done at any place, extraction can be done at any place and the size of course is dynamic.
- `std::list` The same as a vector, but better at inserting elements in random places. Use this only if you have a very granular insertion pattern.

Please take care that if you pass a dynamic array as argument, in most cases it's required to pass a reference or pointer to the dynamic array.

Comment: Thanks for replying and that's some good info there. I am still fairly new to dynamic arrays and i don't think i was taught those types of dynamic arrays, so i guess i must go and do some research lol.

Comment: @user3804711 In general these are both easier and safer to use. With any of these getting a segmentation fault will be quite a hard thing to do. Whereas with traditional arrays as you used them, it's a piece of cake.